# SqlQueryRaw custom model class, dealing with columns of multiple data types, constructor overloading not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, crud, razor-pages

*(Using EntityFrameworkCore v8.0.1)*

For my item management application, I would like to be able to gather the groups for each column of the database.
For instance, the column "Manufacturer" would give the groups:
HP (15)
Dell (13)
ASUS (6)

Which shows the distinct name of each manufacturer and the number of records associated with each. The problems that I face are that **1. there are many columns in the table** and **2. they can be of different types.** I implemented the code below to counter this yet receive the following error message upon execution:
**System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.**
I believe this is due to the 'Name' property being set to *string?*. I was hoping this could be solved by constructor overloading but this does not seem to be the case. I am open to different solutions and thankful for any suggestions.

Model:

```
public class ItemGroup {
    public string? Name { get; set }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public ItemGroup(int name, int count) : this(name.ToString(), count) { }
    public ItemGroup(DateTime name, int count) : this(name.ToShortDateString(), count) { }
    public ItemGroup(string name, int count) : {
        Name = name ?? "(Blank)";
        Count = count;
    }
}
```

To generate the groups I execute an SqlQueryRaw mapped to the ItemGroup custom model class, and add these groups to their specific item column class (not shown). I would like to handle the group 'Name' string conversion within the constructor and not in the SQL query.

```
foreach (var result in _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<ItemGroup>("select " + column.Column + " as 'Name', count(*) as 'Count' from items group by " + column.Column).ToList()) {
    column.Groups.Add(result);
}
```

Column Name & Expected Groups: (sample output)

```
"Manufacturers: HP (15), Dell (13), ASUS (6)" // ItemGroup(string name, int count)
"Type: Laptop (20), Desktops (5), Monitors (11)" // ItemGroup(string name, int count)
"Manufacture Date: 4/14/2019 (10), 6/18/2020 (9)" // ItemGroup(DateTime name, int count)
"Lifespan: 365 (10), 438 (10), 512 (5)" // ItemGroup(int name, int count)
```

The above is the desired result along with the constructor that I want to be called when creating the item groups.

Comment: You need to write a view in the DB that maps everything to your string + int combination.

Comment: @IanKemp That's a good idea, I might go with that if I can't figure anything else out on the c# side. Thank you.